# How do I output a different value from my array, for every iteration of my function;

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, animation, raphael

So here I have a function drawgrowingpie that has a function segment, that draws a pie chart. (this is taken directly from one of the examples page on raphaeljs.com). I want every segment of the pie chart to have it's own a color. I have an array clr, which i want to distribute to every hsb attribute of every segment, but I'm a dumbass and can only figure out how to assign a single variable in my array. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

You can see what im talking about here: http://jsfiddle.net/6hzfH/

Comment: While the demo is nice, you should also include the relevant code here (and I don't mean that you should dump the whole thing, just the part that is troubling you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that code, just pass an aditional parameter to the `segment` function, namely the current iteration, and use it to address the `clr` array. You can check that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DgrgC/)